# When will the chrome browser's network process be closed

Tags: google-chrome, networking, process

An iframe is nested in the page, and the iframe will send some requests. When I open the pop-up window, I immediately close the pop-up window. At this time, some of the iframe requests are in the ‘pending’ state, and my page is stuck. There is no such problem with firefox. What is the reason?